# How to sort a string (in ascending order ) which has numbers seperated with comma in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

This is my code in my javascript:

```
var concatId = document.MyForm.concatIdSaved.value;
```

This is giving me string as 3,2,4,00201,

After 00201 iam getting comma also.
All four values are coming in a single String.

Now i want this string as 00201,2,3,4

Someone please help me on this.

Comment: ***javascript != java***. Anyway, what have you tried?

Comment: are you looking for lexical or numerical order? because 201 > 2, but 0 < 2... It seems you want lexical - in which case the fact these are numbers is a red herring. Can you clarify?

Comment: i dont know from where to start.

Comment: 00201 should come before 2. That what is creating a problem.

Comment: I recommend that you update your question to clarify. Might fix typo in title at the same time. In my experience a well phrased question gets a good answer. And often when you are done stating the question properly, the answer will stare you in the face...

Comment: Ok Floris..ill keep that in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
var concatId = document.MyForm.concatIdSaved.value.split(",").sort().join();
```

Comment: I like this one - "high density code"!

Comment: `Containing numbers` was misleading, this default sort should work for OP. +1

Comment: Above suggestion works like a charm. but i am getting string as ,00201,2,3,4. Could you please suggest how to remove comma coming at first place.

Comment: Add .substring(1) to the end: var concatId = document.MyForm.concatIdSaved.value.split(",").sort().join().substring(1);

Comment: Sorry again:( but now string is coming as 00201,2,3,4  I need 00201,2,3,4,  comma also at the end. Could you please suggest something.

Comment: I got it. Just for info i added "," as document.MyForm.concatIdSaved.value.split(",").sort().join().substring(1)+",";  Thank you all for your help